# Despite being able to run "javac" through the command line, "where javac" doesn't match anything. Why?

Tags: windows, command-line, java

Here are both input/outputs:

Running *`javac`*:

```
D:\>javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Running `where` on `javac`:

```
D:\>where javac
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Comment: What happens if you try `where javac` in `D:\userdata\jobranco\Desktop\aspectJ\workspace\aspect_tests\src\swtproj`?

Comment: What's your PATH variable set to? Does `where javac.exe` return anything?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently (as for Win 7) the implementation of *where* does not handle quotes (") poperly. It's probably better to remove them from your entire PATH environment variable (don't worry about spaces in this case).

```
C:\>set PATH=C:\windows\system32;"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\"
C:\>where javac
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

after removing quotes:

```
C:\>set PATH=C:\windows\system32;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\
C:\>where javac
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javac.exe
```

What might be additionally misleading, is that *where* command could find properly *java* but failed with *javac*. It's because you might have JRE installed as well.